# React Native Application crashing in iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can anyone please help me to figure out this. I am using Flatlist and Inviewport dependencies for a video player integrated list view. I am facing memory issues but works fine in Android devices. It just crashing on iOS (in high end Android devices with RAM 6 Gig works perfectly)

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTou0.png)

**VideoPlayer.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import InViewPort from 'react-native-inviewport';

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {


  pauseVideo = () => {
    if(this.video) {
      this.video.pauseAsync();
    }
  }

  stopVideo = () => {
    if(this.video) {
      this.video.stopAsync();
    }
  }

  playVideo = () => {
    if(this.video) {
      this.video.playAsync();
    }
  }

  handlePlaying = (isVisible) => {
    isVisible ? this.playVideo() : this.stopVideo();
  }

  render() {

    //console.log(this.props);

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <InViewPort onChange={this.handlePlaying}>
          <Video
            ref={ref => {this.video = ref}}
            source={{ uri: 'https://dubaistack.com/beat/'+this.props.url }}
            rate={1.0}
            volume={1.0}
            isMuted={false}
            resizeMode="contain"
            isLooping={true}
            shouldPlay
            style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height - StatusBar.currentHeight, backgroundColor: 'black' }}
          />
          </InViewPort>
        </View>
      )
  }  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

**ShortVideos.js**

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
    View , 
    ScrollView, 
    StyleSheet , 
    Text, 
    Dimensions,
    FlatList,
    StatusBar

} from 'react-native';
import VideoPlayer from '../components/VideoPlayer';

function Item(item) {
    return (
      <VideoPlayer url={item.item.location}/>
    );
  }

function ShortVideos(props) {

        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);

        fetch('https://dubaistack.com/beat/posts/get.php?lvid')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            //console.log(responseJson);
            setLoading(false);
            setData(responseJson);
        })

        if(loading){
            return(
                <Text style={{color:'red'}}>Loading</Text>
            );
        }else{
            return(
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} /> }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    pagingEnabled
                />
            );
        }


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    item: {
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        backgroundColor: '#336699',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 32,
        color: 'white',
      },
})

export default ShortVideos;
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove - this warning you need to use componentWillUnmount like this below and rebuild: -

```
class Home extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    -----
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```